# Banach lattices $X$ for which $L_p(\mu)\subset X$ or $X\subset L_q(\mu)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-lattices

It is well known (see vol. II of Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri's book) that an order continuous Banach lattice $X$ with a weak unit admits a representation as a (in general not closed) ideal of $L_1(\mu)$ for some probability measure $\mu$ so that $L_\infty(\mu)\subset X\subset L_1(\mu)$ with continuous embeddings.

I am interested in conditions on $X$ implying that $L_p(\mu)\subset X$ for some $p>1$, or $X\subset L_q(\mu)$ for some $q<\infty$.

Comment: The discussion in LT2 on Boyd indices is not sufficient for you? Note the remark after the proof of Proposition 2.b.3 that to prove the proposition you only need the estimates on the fundamental function $\|1_{(0,t)}\|_X$.  I think having the needed estimates on the fundamental function is almost equivalent to the containments you want.

Comment: Proposition 2.b.3 and the subsequent remarks are useful for me.